# Need help building SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, build

I have two relayed tables:

```
Fields: ID(prim. key), Title
Values: ID(prim. key), Value, field_id(for. key)
```

In the simple words I have a lot of fields, while each field can contain multiple values.

I need SQL query to select all fields whose values are NOT equal to a given value.

Sample:

```
Assuming I have two fields:
- fld1 { 1,2,5 }
- fld2 { 1,4 }
I need to get fld1 while looking for fields whose value is NOT equal to 4.
```

Comment: Can you clarify what fld1 {1, 2, 5} and fld2 {1, 4} are? A better visualization/separation of your data would be extremely useful

Comment: It's sample records. Two records in the Fields table (fld1 and fld2) and 5 records in the values table: 3 records with values for fld1 (1,2 and 5) and 2 records with values for fld2 (1 and 4)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? or do i misunderstand you completely?

```
select *
  from Fields f
    inner join `Values` v
      on f.id = v.field_id
    where v.value <> 4;
```

Comment: Since `Values` is apparently a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-7.html#idm140307737754128) you need to *escape* it.

Comment: so it is. for some reason i assumed it was reserved only in insert. oh well. fixed

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT title 
FROM `Fields` f
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                 FROM `Values` v
                 WHERE f.id = v.field_id 
                       AND v.`value` = 4);
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c143f/9)

Comment: Thanks, that's the direction I was thinking of, but is it efficient enough assuming I have milions of fields and tens of milions of values?

Comment: If you have proper indexes, should be OK.  You will need to run your benchmarks anyway.

Comment: Shouldn't you want to exclude fields with a value *equal to* 4?